# Apollo client reset and clear store

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm using Apollo client version: 3.7.16 and when the user is switching applications I'm trying to clean the cache of the apollo store.

I tried to use `client.clearStore()` and `client.resetStore()`
the issue is it refetch the queries from the store and some of them use specific variables that aren't available for the other applications then I'm getting an error such as: "Book id '20' does not belong to application: '2'"

code that gets called when switching apps:

```
 onCompleted: (e) => {
  if (e) {
    navigate("home")
    client.clearStore()
    client.resetStore()
  }
},
```

The idea is first to navigate to the new page then clear the store so the previous queries will not be active and then reset store so the UI will get updated